# How to pass a generic array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I need to pass an array to a function in C# where the array may be a string[], int[], or double[] and may be 1 to multiple dimensions.

**Reasoning:**

I am needing to pass an array to a function to calculate its length, similar to:

```
public int getLength(array[] someArray, int dimension)
{
   if(dimension > 0) //get length of dimension 
     return someArray.getLength(dimension);
   else //get length of entire array
     return someArray.Length;
}
```

**Question:**

How can I pass a generic array?

Or

Is there a better way to do this - say convert the array to a List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purpose you cite, just pass `Array someArray` - that should be fine, and covers any number of dimensions. For a *vector* (a 1-dimensional, 0-based array), you can use generics (`GetLength<T>(T[] someArray)`) - but that seems pointless when for a vector `.Length` is more convenient.

But for an unknown number of dimensions (or for a non-vector single-dimensional array), you are limited to `Array`.

Comment: This is what I was needing. I did not know that Array actually existed. Thanks.

Comment: @Todd - it is the base-class for vectors, i.e. `int[] : Array`

Answer (score 0):

If you want `List`-like properties, you can also use `ArrayList`, which holds an arbitrary number of `object`s